# Insert a unix_timestamp into a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to create a function in php that can save a unix_timestamp into a mysql database but I keep getting an error message about invalid parameter numbers.

This is the code for the function:

```
function addNew($array){
$sql = 'INSERT INTO USER (id, acronym, name, password) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());';



$id  = isset($_POST['id'])  ? $_POST['id'] : null;
$acronym   = isset($_POST['acronym'])   ? $_POST['acronym'] : null();
$name   = isset($_POST['name'])   ? strip_tags($_POST['name']) : null;
$password    = isset($_POST['password'])    ? strip_tags($_POST['password']) : null;

$params = array($id, $acronym, $name, $password);
$res=$this->db->ExecuteQuery($sql, $array);

if($res) {
$output = 'Användare skapad!';
}
else {
$output = 'Användare kunde tyvärr ej skapas.<br>';
}
return $output;
}
```

This is the code for the user input:

```
$cont = new CUserAdmin($db);

$id  = isset($_POST['id'])  ? $_POST['id'] : null;
$acronym   = isset($_POST['acronym']) ? strip_tags($_POST['acronym']) : null;
$name   = isset($_POST['name']) ? strip_tags($_POST['name']) : null;
$password   = isset($_POST['password']) ? strip_tags($_POST['password']) : null;

$save = isset($_POST['save'])  ? true : false;

$output = null;
if($save){
$array = array($id, $acronym, $name, $salt );
$output = $cont->addNew($array);
}


// Do it and store it all in variables in the belio container.
$belio['title'] = "Ny användare";

$belio['main'] = <<<EOD
<h1>Skapa ny användare</h1>
<form method=post>
<div class="freebox">
<p><label>Acronym <br> <input type='text' name='acronym'/> </label></p>
<p><label>Name:<br> <input type='text' name='name'/> </label></p>
<p><label>Password:<br> <input type='password' name='salt' /> </label></p>
</div>
<p><input type='submit' name='save' value='Spara'/></p>
<p>{$output}</p>
</form>
EOD;
```

The code does not work however, I get this error message:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables >does not match number of tokens in /home/saxon/students/20141/josj14/www/webflix/belio/src/CDatabase
>   /CDatabase.php on line 121

The problem seems to be the UNIX_TIMESTAMP itself, when I exchange it with a '?' the information is saved to the database.

Is it possible to save a unix timestamp into a databse this way?

Comment: Invalid number of parameters and you don't count that number? Here, try this: count number of question marks in your query and number of elements in `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing related to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` issue , you are doing an **incorrect** mapping. You are mapping the `$password` with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

It is likely that you missed your `unixdatetime` column... I assume it should be this way..

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO USER (id, acronym, name, password , unixdatetime)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());';
```

---

> The problem seems to be the UNIX_TIMESTAMP itself, when I exchange it
>   with a '?' the information is saved to the database.

When you put `?` it does work , because you are mapping everything right , you have four columns `id, acronym, name, password` and four array parameters as you can see here.. `$params = array( $id, $acronym, $name, $password );`

So what you actually did was you substituted the `$password` with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` which led to the *Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables* warning.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement has 3 placeholders.
But you are binding 4 parameter values from the array.
And hence is the exception.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO USER ( id, acronym, name, password ) 
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() );';

$params = array( $id, $acronym, $name, $password );
$res=$this->db->ExecuteQuery($sql, $array);
```

Remove `$password` from array.

**Example**:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO USER  (id, acronym, name, password ) 
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()  );';

$params = array($id, $acronym, $name );
$res=$this->db->ExecuteQuery( $sql, $array );
```

If you are reading password value from userinput then remove the `unix_timestamp()` and put a placeholder there. And to save `unix_timestamp` you should have had another column in your table to accommodate it. say `date_time int unsigned`. Then modify the `insert` as below:

**Example**:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO USER  (id, acronym, name, password, date_time ) 
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, unix_timestamp() );';

$params = array($id, $acronym, $name, $password );
$res=$this->db->ExecuteQuery( $sql, $array );
```

Comment: Ok I think i'm going to try out another strategy, instead of inserting a value directly into $password I want to first insert a unix_timetamp into a column named `salt` and then use `concat`and `md5` to make a encrypted password. First of i want to insert this: `INSERT INTO User (acronym, name, salt) VALUES 
  (?, ?, unix_timestamp()),;` and then `UPDATE User SET password = md5(concat('doe', salt)) WHERE acronym = 'doe';`. Or is there a better whay to do it?

Comment: @belio: Ways can be many. Of them, yours is one. Sounds good. You can use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO USER (id, acronym, name, password) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());';
```

Here you insert timestamp to password field

```
array($id, $acronym, $name, $password);
```

Here you enter an extra variable, $password to a non-existant parameter.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO USER (id, acronym, name, password, date_created) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());';
```

Would work, change date_created to appropriate field name of course

Also you should hash your passwords, storing as plaintext is bad practice